# Why are the parentheses so important when assigning this regex match?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a piece of code:

```
$s = "<sekar kapoor>";
($name) = $s =~ /<([\S\s]*)>/;
print "$name\n";               # Output is 'sekar kapoor'
```

If the parentheses are removed in the second line of code like this, in the variable `$name`:

```
$name = $s =~ /<([\S\s]*)>/;   # $name is now '1'
```

I don't understand why it behaves like this. Can anyone please explain why it is so?

Comment: A note on daxim's edit: In the USA, the word parentheses means `()`, brackets means `[]`, and braces means `{}`. Since Perl was initially designed and written in the USA, the documentation uses these definitions. The English, however, use the word brackets to mean `()`, and this is unfortunate because it causes a great deal of confusion (especially in cases like your question where there are both parentheses and brackets). It is sad that a large group of English speaking people will have to translate those words in their heads, but it is better to standardize on one than to leave the confusion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your first example you have a list context on the left-hand side (you used parentheses); in the second you have a scalar context - you just have a scalar variable.

See the [Perl docs for quote-like ops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), *Matching in list context*:

> If the `/g` option is not used, `m//` in
>   list context returns a list consisting
>   of the subexpressions matched by the
>   parentheses in the pattern, i.e., (`$1
>   , $2 , $3` ...).
>   (Note that here `$1`
>   etc. are also set, and that this
>   differs from Perl 4's behavior.)
>   When there are no parentheses in the
>   pattern, the return value is the list
>   `(1)` for success. With or without
>   parentheses, an empty list is returned
>   upon failure.